# How to include backslash and quotes in Python strings

Tags: python

I've got an array of special characters that looks something like this.

```
specialCharList=['`','~','!','@','#','$','%','^',
             '&','*','(',')','-','_','+','=',
             '|','','{','}','[',']',';',':',
             '"',',','.','<','>','/','?']
```

The problem is, I want to include the ' and the \ characters but can't because they're used for strings and escaping. How would I go about including these characters?

Answer (score 12):

The backslash `\` character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

example:

```
\\  Backslash (\)    
\'  Single quote (')     
\"  Double quote (")
```

Escape characters are documented in the Python Language Reference Manual. If they are new to you, you will find them disconcerting for a while, but you will gradually grow to appreciate their power.

Comment: It is also nice to know that python doesn't have any special meaning for single and double quotes.  So the string `"'"` is equivalent to `'\''` except that the former is easier to read (in my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

You can use single, double or triple quotes for delimiting strings.

So `"'"`, `'"'` are ways to have a quote character in your string.

Python's "triple quotes" are either three double-quotes in a row, or three single-quotes in a row. However, e.g. `'''''''` does not work to surround a single quote in triple-single quotes - it will be seen as an empty string in triple-single quotes, and then an unmatched single quote. We can, however, use `'''"'''` or `"""'"""` (although there is not much of a point in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The readability of your list could be greatly improved by putting your special characters in a string:

```
>>> SCL = "`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=|{}[],;:'.><?/" + '"\\'
>>> specialCharacters = list(SCL)
```

We're combining two strings, one delimited by `"` and where we put `'`, the second delimited by `'` and where we put `"` and `\\` (that we have to escape, so we have to put `'\\'`).

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt module called `string` in Python. This can be used.

```
>>>
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>>
>>> list(string.punctuation)
['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
>>>
```