# How to write \t to file using Python

Tags: python

I build one web and user can enter directory path in form.

My program will extract the path and write into one file.

My question is when the path include some special word such as \t \n, the program can't write file correctly.

For example:
C:\abc\test will become C:\abc[TAB]est

How can I change the string into other type like raw string and write file correctly ?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576418/how-to-include-backslash-and-quotes-in-python-strings/12576426#12576426

Answer (score 2):

Use `r'C:\abc\test'` or `'C:\\abc\\test'` when you enter your strings

Answer (score 1):

> ... user can enter directory path in form.
>
> ...
>
> My question is when the path include some special word such as \t \n, the program can't write file correctly.

Uh, no. Python is perfectly capable of distinguishing between `'\t'` and `'\\t'` *unless you are doing something to confuse it*.

```
>>> raw_input()
<Ctrl-V><Tab>
'\t'
>>> raw_input()
\t
'\\t'
```